# How to install proprietary Nvidia driver in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, nvidia

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an AMD processor and NVIDIA graphics card machine.

How do I load the proprietary driver to be able to install the open source driver for **Nvidia GTX 560** or how do I install it at all?

I have read somewhere that the 12.04 LTS open source driver for nvidia GTX 560 crashes, Will it work or are there any special problems to look out for.

Once i select "Try ubuntu without installing" or " install ubuntu" i get the logo of a loading screen, then my video card crashes, and my 2 lcd displays blink and turn off. Everything else seems to be functioning right though. There is activity on the USB drive, and on the hard drives like it was detecting them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have nearly enough details for anyone to give a meaningful answer. First of all, your headline indicates that the installation program crashes. Where does it crash? What happens? You can install the proprietary driver very easily when Ubuntu is installed, a popup will appear saying that "proprietary drivers are available", but let's ignore that for a second.

If you are having issues with installing Ubuntu graphically I can recommend trying the [minimal Ubuntu install ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD/) instead. Put that iso on a USB stick and boot from it, make sure your computer is connected to the Internet (via ethernet cable if possible) and choose what packets to install. Most likely "Ubuntu Desktop" will do fine. This installer is graphically very simple so you should get no driver problems during installation.

There might be a way to run a "text installer" with the normal installation media, but I'd recommend trying the minimal ISO first.

If you encounter any problems, update your question and comment here and I'll update my answer :)

Comment: Sorry that i didn't clarify better, Once i select "Try ubuntu without installing"  or " install ubuntu"  i get the logo of a loading screen, then my video card crashes, and my 2 lcd displays blink and turn off. Everything else seems to be functioning right though. There is activity on the USB drive, and on the hard drives like it was detecting them.

Comment: Definitely sounds like something that has to do with the graphical installer. I'm quite sure that you'll succeed in installing Ubuntu with the minimal ISO, if you're not scared of a somewhat more spartan GUI experience and you have Internet access via ethernet ready :)

Comment: Solved it with the minimal install :). The graphics did crash again after being installed, however when it got to the login screen they loaded again, installed the proprietary nvidia drivers and al ( including loading screen ) works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked! (Please mark the above post as the answer if it answered your question)